# Given, $n^4\lt10^n$ for a fixed positive integer $n\ge2$, then which of the following is correct?

Tags: inequality, contest-math

The following question is taken from the practice set of JEE exam.

> Given, $n^4\lt10^n$ for a fixed positive integer $n\ge2$, then which of the following is correct?
>
> - A) $(n+1)^4\lt10^{n+1}$
> - B) $(n+1)^4\gt10^{n+1}$
> - C) $(n-1)^4\lt10^{n+1}$
> - D) None of these

Multiplying the given inequality by $10$, I get $10n^4\lt10^{n+1}$. But not able to proceed next.

Or, $n\lt10^{n/4}\implies(n+1)^4\lt(1+10^{n/4})^4$. Not able to finish this either.

I tried taking log too, but couldn't reach anywhere.

If I take $n=3,4$ then options A) and C) satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

The key is **trying** to prove that option A is true, and option B is false, which **would then imply** that option C is also true.

Re option A, when transitioning the inequality 
from $n^4 < 10^n$ 
to $(n+1)^4 < 10^{(n+1)}$:

note that with $n \geq 2,$ 
the LHS is being multiplied by $\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^4$ 
while the RHS is being multiplied by $(10)$.

It is therefore immediate that option A is true when $n \geq 2,$ since then
$\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^4 \leq (3/2)^4 < 10.$

Thus, option A is correct, as well as option C.

---

Since option A is correct, option B must be false.

Answer (score 1):

$(n-1)^4 < n^4 < 10^n < 10^{n+1}$
So C is TRUE.

Since others seem TRUE also. Shouldn't your question be
"Which of the following **are** correct?"

Comment: I think you are right.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

First of all, we must check these conditions one by one. Let us first test condition A and then you try to solve the others by yourself.

Since $n^4 < 10^n$, assume that condition A is true. That means $(n + 1)^4 < 10^{n + 1}$. Dividing this by $n^4 < 10^n$, we get that $\frac{(n + 1)^4}{n^4} < 10.$ Taking the $4$th root of both sides, we get $\frac{n + 1}{n} < 1.78$ approximately. However, if $n$ is very high, this is a counterexample, because the higher $n$ is, the closer this statement gets to $1$. Hence, condition A is not true for all $n \geq 2$ by contradiction.

Do similar calculations for B and C to get your answer.

Comment: "dividing this by..." doesn't work...

Comment: @abiessu oops I just realized.